# jQuery and modifiying a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following and it works as it lets me control the the background color of a button. However, I do not have any control over when the button is hovered on.

```
popUpDialog.parent().find('button:contains("Save")').addClass('gb').removeClass('ui-state-default');
popUpDialog.parent().find('button:contains("Save")').addClass('gb').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
```

Is there a way to modify the hover class or effect what happens to the button when it gets a hover?

Comment: why not use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: can't you use `.mouseover()`? (http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
$(function(){
    var button = popUpDialog.parent().find('button:contains("Save")');

    button.addClass('gb')
        .hover(function(){
            $(this).removeClass(''ui-state-hover'');
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass(''ui-state-default'); 
        });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the hover event for the button which will keep the class from being added in the first place:

```
popUpDialog.parent().find('button:contains("Save")').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')
```